# How to find twilio usage in say last 1 hour or last 15 minutes from now using Twilio API?

Tags: twilio

I want to set up a twilio monitoring check to see the usage is last 15 minutes or may be last 1 hour from now. Basically, I want to see how many SMS or VMs were sent in last x minutes from current time. Any ways to do that using Twilio APIs. I can find the usage for today, but did not find a break up for last few minutes.

Comment: Which language are you tying to use to get that information? What have you tried so far?

Comment: could you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The `DateSent` parameter is returned in RFC 2822 format. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance

Example: `Mon, 11 April 2016 15:52:01 +0000`

You will have to do some work on the backend to filter time from this data. You can give it a try in a [spreadsheet](https://github.com/devinrader/TwilioSheet/blob/master/README.md).